# Context initialization failed when deploying Spring project on Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat7, web.xml

I am using JavaConfig for bootstrapping configuration, and it works well when I run local as Spring Boot App. But when I create a war file and try to deploy on a remote Tomcat7 server it complains about there is no web context loader:

ERROR o.s.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/ < NONE> ]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/< NONE>]

Do I have to declare a web context when I am using the Spring Boot Servlet Initializer ?

This is my current web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>my service</display-name>
   <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </init-param>
   <init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>
          com.myserviceclass.login.WebConfig
    </param-value>
  </init-param>

<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```